# About SQL join statement

Tags: sql

I have three SQL tables: TableA, TableB, and TableC

TableA is a primary key table with foreign keys in TableB and TableC (i.e. TableA is connected to TableB and TableC separately).

Example:

```
TableA: tableA_id
TableB: tableB_id, tableA_id
TableC: tableC_id, tableA_id
```

I want to return records from tableA, which matches with the record in tableB (inner join), but returned records are not in tableC. Can this be done with a single SQL statement?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select a.x, b.y
from tablea a
inner join tableb b on a.x = b.x
where not exists (select null 
                  from tablec c 
                  where a.x = c.x)
```

Answer (score 0):

Think this is one way to do it - everything from a that matches with b, but not in c...

```
select a.*
  from TableA
  join TableB
    on TableA.tablea_id=TableB.tablea_id
  left outer join TableC
    on TableA.tablea_id=tableC.Tablea_id
 where Tablec.tablea_id is null
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add another join for table C, specifically, a [left outer join](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29#Left_outer_join), and then filter for rows `where Tablec.tablea_id is null`